# Send an email with a profile picture (avatar) using Python through Gmail

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, mime, smtplib

I have a profile picture set for example@gmail.com, however, when I send an email with Python using `smtplib` and `MIMEMultipart` the profile picture does not show up for the reciever.
I authenticate myself using the following way:

```
    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465) as smtp_server:
        smtp_server.login(send_from, password)
        smtp_server.sendmail(send_from, recipient, msg.as_string())
```

where `msg = MIMEMultipart('related')`.

I have come across with BIMI, however, I have no idea how to implement that by using Gmail instead of my own domain. For this project, I must use Gmail.

**EDIT:**

The e-mail is constructed in the following way:

```py
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.utils import formataddr

body: str = "Help me!"
msg = MIMEMultipart('related')
msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'html'))
msg['Subject'] = "Not working"
msg['From'] = formataddr(("John", "john@gmail.com"))
msg['To'] = "recipient@gmail.com"
with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465) as smtp_server:
    smtp_server.login("john@gmail.com", "THIS_is_My_Password")
    smtp_server.sendmail("john@gmail.com", "recipient@gmail.com", msg.as_string())
```

Comment: Assuming Gmail will display profile pics on messages sent over SMTP, I think we need to see how you are constructing the email message.

Comment: @snakecharmerb I really appreciate your answer. I have added the details to the question. Please help me.

Comment: As an aside, your code seems to be written for Python 3.5 or earlier. The email library was overhauled in 3.6 and is now quite a bit more versatile and logical. Probably throw away what you have and start over with the [examples from the `email` documentation.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html)

Comment: But of course, without any headers to display an avatar, why did you expect this to work?