# smtplib send email with set email image

Tags: python, smtp, smtplib

**i try to send email with set email image **

> Next to the message title there is a small picture. I am trying to change it to reflect the nature of the email sent in each sending process

[image]

```
def check(line):
   arre = str(line).split(':')
   print(arre)
   mail_username="username"
   mail_password="password"
   try:
      from_addr = mail_username
      to_addrs=('myemail@gmail.com')
      HOST = "smtpDomain"
      print(HOST)
      PORT = 587
      smtp = smtplib.SMTP(HOST)
      smtp.connect(HOST,PORT)
      time.sleep(2)
      smtp.ehlo()
      smtp.starttls()
      try:
         smtp.login(mail_username,mail_password)
         print ("goodlogin")
         smtp.set_debuglevel(1)
         msg = MIMEMultipart()
         msg['From'] = "emample@example.com"
         msg['To'] = to_addrs
         msg['Reply-to'] = "emample@example.com"
         msg['Subject']='test message'
         msg.add_header('Content-Type', 'text/html')
         data = line
         msg.attach(MIMEText(data, 'html', 'utf-8'))
         print(smtp)
         smtp.sendmail(from_addr,[msg['To']],msg.as_string())
         print ("done")
      except Exception as ee:
         print( ee)
      smtp.quit()
   except Exception as ee:
                          print ("asd")
                          print (ee)
```

I need help on how to send a different image

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "set image". Do you have a specific image you want to attach? Do you not know how to add attatchments? Is this a duplicate of e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7755501/embed-picture-in-email?

Comment: As an aside, it looks like your `email` code was written for an older Python version. The `email` module in the standard library was overhauled in Python 3.6 to be more logical, versatile, and succinct; new code should target the (no longer very) new `EmailMessage` API. Probably throw away this code and start over with modern code from [the Python `email` examples documentation.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html)

Comment: Or are you trying to change the image associated with the sender in some clients? See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77687137/send-an-email-with-a-profile-picture-avatar-using-python-through-gmail

Comment: yes trying to change the image associated with the sender in some clients or message contant type